# General Isomorphism proof given a section and a cancellation law

Tags: category-theory, axioms

Suppose $f: A →B$ and $s: B → A$ and $f∘s=1_B$ and for every object T and any pair of maps $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $t_1: T → A$ and $t_2 : T → A$, it is true that if $f∘t_1=f∘t_2$ then $t_1 = t_2$. Note that A, B and C are objects in a general category.

Question: If above conditions hold, can it be proved that $f$ is an isomorphism using only basic general axioms of a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based upon @LordSharktheUnknown 's hint.

Consider the map $f \circ (s\circ f):A\rightarrow B$.

Using associative property of composition of maps, 
$$f \circ (s\circ f)=(f\circ s)\circ f.$$

Now, since $s$ is a section for $f$, 
$$(f\circ s)\circ f=1_B\circ f=f.$$

Now we have shown that, 
$$f\circ (s\circ f)=f.$$

But also using identity law, 
$$f\circ 1_A=f.$$

This was what @LordSharktheUnknown's hint expressed as $f\circ (s\circ f)=f\circ 1_A$.

Since $f$ is a monomorphism, by definition, 
$$[f\circ (s\circ f)=f\circ 1_A]\Rightarrow [s\circ f = 1_A].$$

Now, we have shown that,

$$s\circ f = 1_A (New)\ and \ f\circ s = 1_B \ (Given).$$ Therefore, $f$ is an isomorphism, and $s$ is its inverse.(Q.E.D.)

Notice, similarly, given retraction $r$ for a $f$ and $f$ being epimorphism, it may be, in which I have high degree of confidence, showed that $f$ is isomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't
$$f\circ S\circ f=f\circ\text{id}_A?$$

Comment: @jaspreetsingh $f\circ S$ is an identity surely?

Comment: Yes. @Lord Shark the Unknown

Comment: Also, using $f∘S = 1_B$, $(f∘S)∘f = 1_B∘f$.

Comment: @jaspreetsingh Exactly!

Comment: But that does not prove that $f$ is an isomorphism. @Lord Shark the Unknown

Comment: @jaspreetsingh Ah! But what is the property of $f$ you are assuming?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61173/discussion-between-jaspreet-singh-and-lord-shark-the-unknown).

Comment: I thank you, for the hint you gave me, which when closely examined revealed that, indeed, you were right. I am posting the full answer in addition to your hint.